# Creating a grid layout for GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

I'm writing an application in C and i'm using GTK+ for the GUI part. I was reading about the layout part and how I need to organize my into into grids using vertical boxes and horizontal boxes. However I read on some forum that the use of gtk_vbox_new() function is deprecated. What are the best ways to create a grid so that I can position my widgets using GTK+? Should I use a table and just juggle with that or is there any way that I can position my elements similar to how I position elements in HTML with CSS?

Comment: GtkTable has been deprecated as well, GtkGrid has taken its place, too. Just to warn you about not to go from one deprecated widget to another, if you want to avoid deprecated widgets in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gtk_vbox_new` is deprecated in favor of using `gtk_box_new` and passing in `GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL`. If you need a tabular layout, `GtkGrid` is the way to go (don't use the deprecated `GtkTable`).

A good way to design your layout is to use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/). Even if you end up hard-coding the widgets instead of using `GtkBuilder`, Glade will allow you to quickly layout the widgets and experiment with different designs in real time.

Comment: I will use Glade. Thank you :)

Comment: Glade has bugs .